# Assign an array of a single string and then fetch its value after modifying it

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have declared an array in viewDidLoad.

```
 -(void) viewDidLoad{
   status=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
   [status addObject:@"Pending"];
 }
```

Now in some function I need to change the value of "Pending" to "Approved". and then check that condition in cellforRow. What I am currently doing is :

```
some function: [[ objectAtIndex:0] addObject: "Approved"];

cellForRow:  

if( [[status objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"Pending"){
  //do this
}
else if ([[status objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:@"Approved"){
  //do that
}
```

It is throwing an exception:

```
NSInvalidArgumentException :[__ NSCFCConstantString addObject:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: according to me you need to use NSMutableDictionary rather then array, and then after check the value of key of status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need to add code is like that in your some function

```
[status replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:"Approved"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Replace value with index number of an Array

```
[yourArray replaceObjectAtIndex:0 withObject:@"Approved"];
```

:)